# How does google handle pages with similar/same content but with a different context?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, pages

Let's say we have XY HTML pages, where some of content is shared.

Example page 1.

Url: example.com/lists/best-rated-food-italy

Title: Best rated food in Italy

```
<h1>Best rated food in Italy</h1>
<h2>1. Bolognese</h2>
<p>Something about bolognese</p>
<h2>2. Pizza</h2>
<p>Something about pizza</p>
.....
```

Example page 2.

Url: example.com/lists/most-popular-food-bologna

Title: Most popular food in Bologna

```
<h1>Best rated food in Italy</h1>
<h2>1. Random dish from bologna</h2>
<p>Something about  dish from bologna</p>
<h2>2. Pizza</h2>
<p>Something about pizza</p>
<h2>3. Bolognese</h2>
<p>Something about bolognese</p>
```

Example page 3.

Url: example.com/lists/most-popular-food-italy

Title: Most popular food in Italy

```
<h1>Best rated food in Italy</h1>
<h2>1. Pesto</h2>
<p>Something about pesto</p>
<h2>2. Pizza</h2>
<p>Something about pizza</p>
<h2>3. Bolognese</h2>
<p>Something about bolognese</p>
```

As you can see, those pages have slightly different context, but on some occasions, it will share content, which will be the same amongst different pages.

Does Google penalize this type of content, as a duplicate content or it is clever enough to understand a different context of each page?
If so, are there any non canonical HTML/TAG changes that can be done to avoid penalizations, because this content is not canonical to each other.

Comment: Users that land on those pages from search engines wouldn't know the context of the pages.  Context is only apparent to users that browse to those pages from other places on your site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller will google penalize content such as this, or mark it as "duplicate" ?

Comment: Do you care if they do? When Google finds duplicate content it usually just chooses one of the pages to index excludes the other pages.

Comment: I should care, right @stephenostermiller ? Content is not duplicated by context, just by part of it's content, and google may consider my domain spammy because of that and I would like to know if that's the case.

If I search "worst cars" on google, I would expect them to return list of worst cars, not list of best cars, which are cannonzed by "worst cars" page.

Comment: You need to read [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site).    Duplicate content is only seen as spammy when it is trying to deceive search engines.  For example when it is plagarized from another source and passed off as original.   Google finds duplicate content all the time on all sorts of sites for all sorts of reasons.   Mostly it just ignores all duplicates and indexes just one copy of content.

Comment: Google isn't going to penalize your site in any way for having several pages with overlapping content.  At worst it will decide not to index pages that are substantially duplicative.   To your case about "best cars" and "worst cars", there shouldn't be any overlap between those two lists and there shouldn't be any duplicate content.   But if you had pages for "Best Cars for Men with Beards" and "Best cars for Men without Beards," the lists would be pretty same.  Having a beard has little bearing in car choice.  Google might decide to index only one of those two pages.